# How to display two images side by side in multiple screen size?

Tags: android

As there are many post about multiple screen size support.
I have a very serious doubt.
I want to display an image twice such that they are side by side in multiple android screen size but the problem is how would I know the width  and height of the image to be chosen for this purpose?
I have taken an image 48*48 for mdpi and similarly for others hdpi xhdpi but that is too small for it.
So is there any way to find out that required size?
I am using wrap content for both height and width in image view to display the image but there is some space after having two image side by side. I wanted to make it fit the screen.
I studied about multiple  screen sizes and all but how to adjust that image pixel for mdpi?
How would I know the required image size for mdpi????? So that I  could make image size according for hdpi and xhdpi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout weight is good if you want 50% each

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is working now but how to add more images like that below these images. I am unable to add coz its linearlayout with horizontal allignment. I have tried vertical still not working.

Comment: change rootview( Linear layout ) orientation to vertical, add another linear layout around two imageview with orientation horizontal.